# Are all zeros valid SPI read/write data?

Tags: spi

If yes, how does the hardware know if there's really data or not since the level on the MOSI/MISO line never changes.

Comment: Maybe you could add some more information to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I assume that with SPI you mean Serial Peripheral Interface.*

According to wikipedia, the data is sent like this:

> During each SPI clock cycle, a full duplex data transmission occurs. The master sends a bit on the MOSI line and the slave reads it, while the slave sends a bit on the MISO line and the master reads it. This sequence is maintained even when only one-directional data transfer is intended.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Data_transmission).

Because it works with a clock, sending (only) zeros should work.

---

Besides that, with something like the [Manchester code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code), the MOSI/MISO line would change. I'm not sure if this can be used with the Serial Peripheral Interface though.

Comment: Yes, I think the clock is the key here! If there's a clock pulse, then there's valid data, even if it's all zeros. Thanks!